# C# Code Contracts -- How to ensure that a collection of items contains items with unique properties?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, code-contracts

Basically, I have the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ICollection<MyObject> coll)
    {
        Contract.Requires(coll != null);
        Contract.Requires(Contract.ForAll(coll, obj => obj != null));
        Contract.Requires(Contract.ForAll(coll, obj => (????)); //What goes here?
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public object PropA { get; set; }
    public object PropB { get; set; }
}
```

The requirements are:

- All PropA items in the collection are unique (no duplicates)
- All PropB items in the collection are unique (no duplicates)

Can't seem to figure out what to do here for my `Contract.ForAll(...)` statement.

---

Bonus: if I can combine the `Contract.ForAll(...)` statements without ruining the code contracts?

Comment: At first glance it looks like the input to you function should be an ISet<> instead of a an ICollection, but perhaps that an oversimplification...

Comment: What AVee said. I normally wouldn't encode a complex prerequisite like this in a `Requires`. If you're using the static checker, it's impossible to prove it. Better to use a class like Set which encodes the pre-requisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following should do the trick:

```
Contract.Requires(
    Contract.ForAll(
        coll, 
        obj => (coll.Where(x=>x.PropA = obj.PropA).Count==1)
    )
);
```

The theory is that it filters coll to only those elements whose value of PropA is the same as the object we are looking at. There should only be one of these (itself).

You can repeat similarly for B.

And it is in theory trivial to combine the ForAll lambda expressions but I'm not sure you'd want to. Surely it would be nice to know which condition fails if one does rather than lumping them all together and knowing that something failed but not really what...

If you can give a bit of leeway on the format you can try:

```
Contract.Requires(
    Contract.ForAll(
        coll.GroupBy(x=>x.PropA), 
        group => group.Count==1)
    )
);
```

This is a similar principle but I think will do the counting more efficiently since the group by and count will be more efficient (I think - I've not tested and am not famiilar with the inner workings of the linq methods).

Another method:

```
HashSet<object> propAValues = new HashSet<object>();
Contract.Requires(
    !coll.Any(x=>!hashset.Add(x.PropA))
);
```

This uses a hashset and the fact that Add returns false if the element already exists. In this case the moment an Add generates a false (and thus the lambda expression is true) then Any will return true which since it is negated will fail the test.

Whether this method is sensible or not probably depends on how big your objects are (and thus the potential memory implications of doubling up your object set. It will however take least iterations to terminate compared to the other methods here (since the other methods need to look at every object in the collection, potentially several times whereas this last one could potentially stop after looking at two entries).

Comment: This works, though I am hoping there is another, more efficient LINQ call/method than this.

Comment: I've updated with a second bit of code that should do the same thing but in a different way. It doesn't match the format you asked for but I can't think how to make it quicker any other way.

Answer (score 2):

I might be completely off base here, never having used contracts, but assuming `Contract.Requires` can be passed an arbitrary `bool`, can't you just do:

```
Contract.Requires(coll.GroupBy(o => o.PropA).Count() == coll.Count);
```

and similarly for `PropB` ?

Comment: Ah yes, that is a nicer version of groupby than my one I think.

Comment: @Chris: I also like your version as well... it seems that it *could* be more efficient since the LINQ will fail once it hits a group that has more than one item in it. This one must count the number of groups (so it must go through the entire collection... twice?). Can't figure out which one is "easier to read" since efficiency is probably negligible between the two at this point.

Comment: Assuming you remember what GroupBy returns (which I usually don't for some reason) then I'd say they are about the same. A very brief comment will probably be useful here anyway though to explain what is required in english (eg "PropA must be unique throughtout the collection") and you can easily enough just add a one line to that (eg "count of group by PropA equalling count of objects means they are unique").

Comment: I'm thinking you could probably do something with `IEnumerable.Any` too if efficiency and quitting early is important. I'm trying to think of the best thing to do but at the very least create an empty HashSet and `coll.Any(x=>!hashset.Add(x.PropA))`. The inner thing will evaluate to true only when the add returns false - ie the item is already in the hashset. It does require more memory to do but I think may be the least iteration through coll if that is a consideration. (since it will iterate through only one time and terminate that runthrough when it finds a duplicate).

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detail on that last one. And I think I should stop trying to think of lots of different ways to do the same thing with linq and go do something more useful. :)